# Lifting polymorphic values with typeclasses

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I tried to implement automatic lifting into `Either` types: pure values would be
lifted with `Right`, already `Either` values with `id`.

```
-- Wrapper for pure, non-Either values
newtype ConstRight a = ConstRight a

class LiftEither t e a where
  liftEither :: t -> Either e a

instance LiftEither (Either e a) e a where
  liftEither = id

instance LiftEither (ConstRight a) e a where
  liftEither (ConstRight a) = Right a

x :: Either () (Int -> Int)
x = liftEither $ ConstRight (id :: Int -> Int)

y :: Either () (a -> a)
y = liftEither $ ConstRight id

z :: Either (a -> a) ()
z = liftEither $ Left id
```

However, only monomoprhic values can be lifted using this method. The
definitions of `y` and `z` yield type errors:

```
No instance for (LiftEither (ConstRight (a1 -> a1)) () (a -> a))
  arising from a use of ‘liftEither’
The type variable ‘a1’ is ambiguous

No instance for (LiftEither (Either (a0 -> a0) b0) (a -> a) ())
  arising from a use of ‘liftEither’
The type variables ‘b0’, ‘a0’ are ambiguous
```

This could be solved with functional dependencies, but `ConstRight a` does not determine `e`:

```
class LiftEither t e a | t -> e a where
  liftEither :: t -> Either e a
```

I also tried using associated types, but I could not come up with a suitable
definition for the `ConstRight` instance:

```
class LiftEither t where
  type Result t
  liftEither :: t -> Result t

instance LiftEither (Either e a) where
  type Result (Either e a) = Either e a
  liftEither = id

instance LiftEither (ConstRight a) where
  type Result (ConstRight a) = Either e a -- e is not in scope
  liftEither (ConstRight a) = Right a
```

Is it possible to implement this for polymorphic values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always move as much information as possible from the instance head to the instance constraints. Here, the correct instance can be determined purely based on whether we have an `Either` or a `ConstRight`, so there is no need to constrain instance heads further.

`LiftEither (Either e a) e a` is overly restrictive, because it demands that the two `a`-s and the two `e`-s can be determined to be equal at the point of matching the instance head. The other instance has the same issue. Instead, you should move the type equalities to the constraints. That way GHC can happily match the instances and try solving the constraints later.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances #-}

newtype ConstRight a = ConstRight a

class LiftEither t e a where
  liftEither :: t -> Either e a

instance (e ~ f, a ~ b) => LiftEither (Either e a) f b where
  liftEither = id

instance (a ~ b) => LiftEither (ConstRight a) e b where
  liftEither (ConstRight a) = Right a
```

Now all your examples work.

Comment: So much simpler than my deleted version.